# Unable to call `/oauth2/v2.0/token` even with the correct redirect/reply URL

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory

I am following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) and currently stuck at 3rd step, [Get a token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#3-get-a-token):

I have no issue with the 2nd step, [Get authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#2-get-authorization) as I could sign in (from the browser) and it responded with the `code` for the next step (*3rd step*).

BUT when it gave me the response below when sending a POST request (`/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`):

```json
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: 'afef958a-7070-4b2d-9006-65b28c9aed43'.\r\nTrace ID: 2e478767-2adc-468c-b716-6134ca2d3a04\r\nCorrelation ID: 7117f8d0-2a9f-4110-8257-b32753876afb\r\nTimestamp: 2022-01-06 08:22:48Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50011
    ],
    "timestamp": "2022-01-06 08:22:48Z",
    "trace_id": "2e478767-2adc-468c-b716-6134ca2d3a04",
    "correlation_id": "7117f8d0-2a9f-4110-8257-b32753876afb",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50011"
}
```

---

- My request in Postman [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tykpp.png)
- My Azure config [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i64Tq.png)
- My response on browser [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g56KX.png)
- My code (PHP):

```php
$response = $client->request(
    "POST",
    "/common/oauth2/v2.0/token",
    [
        "headers" => [
            "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        ],
        "form_params" => [
            "tenant" => $tenantId,
            "client_id" => $clientId,
            "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
            "scope" => "User.Read",
            "code" => $_GET["code"],
            "redirect_uri" => $replyUrl,
            "client_secret" => $clientSecret,
        ]
    ]
);
```

---

Note:

- I have tried with `Accounts in any organizational directory` and `Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts`, both of them are giving me the same response
- I am sure the client secret is correct
- I am sure the redirect/reply URL is correct too
- I have done enough research online, but no similar solutions that could solve this issue

Comment: I've put a tentative answer, but please update your question with the points I've specific so we can help better.

Comment: that's much better, thanks - now the right people can help - I see you're using PHP, for instance, so my answer as not applicable for that.

Comment: When you are authorizing how are you saving the `code`? 

Basically, this is what I did, I created app reg added added two permission `User.Read, offline_access` then I called the `authorize` endpoint and copied the code browser URL bar. 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUS8t.png)
Once I have that `code` I called `token` endpoint provided the similar value as you are doing and able to get the token. I see your `code` value starting with M are you sure you are getting the correct one? Also I tried `authorize` step directly on Browser and `token` step with PostMan

Comment: Did you get a chance to look on the above suggestion?

Comment: Yes, the code that contains M. is the response after authorisation.

Comment: @JingHuiP. Could you please try by creating a new app registration? Please reverify tenant Id, client Id and reply URL that you are passing in request as well as in **app registration**.? Issue is not getting repro at my end so it would be better if you retry again and verify things,

Comment: @JingHui P. -Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when the login code in your app (js/ts) is not setting the `redirectUrl` value to something that matches what your app is *configured* to answer as a redirect Url in your Azure portal. You haven't sent enough code to see what your redirect looks like, but it's not clear why you're doing it by hand (instead of using MSAL), and also why you've tagged this as "microsoft-teams" - this is important because, if you are building a Teams tag, then the usual process is a little different for Teams.

Update: the original question makes it clear now that this is a PHP scenario, which my answer above does not address - fyi to anyone reading this answer.

Comment: Hi Hilton Giesenow, I have updated the question. I am sorry for the unclear question and misunderstanding of `microsoft-teams` tag.